# FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have taken a reference from : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_custom.htm and developed below code.

But it gives me the following error.

```
FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
```

**MyController**

```
public class MyController {
    private final Account account;

    public MyController(){
        Id newId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        System.debug('New ID : '+newId);
        account = [SELECT Id, Name, Site FROM Account WHERE Id = :newId];
    }

    public Account getAccount(){
        return account;
    }

    public PageReference save(){
        update account;
        return null;
    }
}
```

**MyControllerVF**

```
<apex:page controller="MyController" tabStyle="Account">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock title="Congratulations {!$User.FirstName}">
            You belong to Account Name: <apex:inputField value="{!account.name}"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

**My input screen.**

[image]

Comment: Its a good practice to add limit 1 to the query when getting one record, also do you actually have any record in the system that matches that Id? try pasting the record id in url and see where it takes you

Comment: make sure to put the `?id=<an account id>` in the url when requesting the page.

Comment: @martin, put your comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT added upsert + exception handling**

This is not going to fix the problem - while the error checking is good, it won't prevent the error mentioned here from occurring.

You shouldn't query straight to a single `sObject` - you need to query to a list. Eg:

```
Account[] accounts = [SELECT Id, Name, Site FROM Account WHERE Id = :newId];
if (!accounts.isEmpty()){
  account = accounts[0];
}
else {
  account = new Account();
}
```

Then your save method can `upsert` the Account.

```
public PageReference save(){
  try {
    upsert account;
    return null;
  }
  catch (Exception e){
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(
      ApexPages.Severity.Error, 
      'Line ' + e.getLineNumber() + ' ' + e.getMessage()
    )); 
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always query in a `List` like:

```
Id newId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
System.debug('New ID : '+newId);
if (newId == NULL) { 
    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(
        ApexPages.Severity.Error, 
        System.Label.UnabletoFindIdParameter // make sure to create the custom label
    )); 
} else {
    List<account> accounts = [SELECT Id, Name, Site FROM Account WHERE Id = :newId];
    if(accounts.size() > 0){
        /* We got record from database process it using accounts[0] */
    }else{
        /* No record found with the Id provided in the URL. */
    }
}
```